# How do you refresh a form to populate with database change, smoother than .Hide / .Show?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a combo box that displays the change on a complete refresh of the form, but the new one ends up changing location and is not a smooth transition as you would expect. As I update the information in text boxes and use save button, I want the form to clear and combo box to populate with new data saved in my database. Here is my code now that works, but not the way I like.

```
      finally
            {
                con.Close();
                frmBooks mainForm = new frmBooks();
                mainForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
```

It seems like it would be very simple to either lock the location to .Show() in the same location or some use of .Refresh(), but I have failed at getting that to work. I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 frmBooks mainForm = new frmBooks();  
 mainForm.Show(); --- > Show new Form and 
 this.Hide(); --> Hide Current open form
```

Maybe you can put your combobox loading and clearing of fields on a method and call it anywhere on your events.

```
pivate void refreshForm()
{

 //you dsource
 cmbox.DataSource = youredsource
 cmbox.DisplayMember = "YouTableColumn";

 textbox.text = string.Empty()
 //anything you want to clear

}
```

something like this:

```
     finally
        {
            con.Close();
           //refresh combo box and clear fields on form
           refreshForm();
        }
```

Regards